# Red Hat 7 query table name with space and dollar sign

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I have an old server that is running on RHEL6, this server has an application that connects with a external MS SQL server.
All is working fine on my RHEL6.

Now we bought a new server and i have installed RHEL7 on it. I copied all php files. Every thing is working fine except queries with dollar sign and spaces give now an error : invalid object name.

the query is use is :

```
$sql = 'SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo.[My Database$Cus_ Info Entry]';
$sql1 = mssql_query($sql, $conn_nav) or die("Problem with query? " . $sql );

while( $rec = mssql_fetch_assoc( $sql1 ) )
{
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump( $rec );
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

It works on RHEL6 but not on 7, and i cannot figure out why it doesn't work. The error message is : Invalid object name

What i am doing wrong? Since this works on RHEL6 i am guessing maybe a configuration issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I put a backslash character on the dollar sign to escape the character.